# VBA to save a Sheet as CSV breaks existing module

Tags: excel, vba, module

I am trying to build a VBA sub that will copy a sheet and save it as a CSV. I am using the tried and true method of:

1) Copying the sheet

2) Opening a new workbook

3) Pasting the copied data into that new workbook

4) Saving that workbook as a CSV

The source sheet contains several formulas and a module in two cells, so I planned to use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. However, running the sub throws an Error 1004 and breaks the modules in the source sheet (they then display as #VALUE).

I tried stepping through the sub, and the problem seems to be with `.PasteSpecial` method / something in the source sheet. When I get the `.PasteSpecial` step, the module contained in the source sheet launches, and then I'm stuck in a loop.

As side a note, the `Set csvFileName` line refers to a cell that concatenates the filename value before the sub is run. I don't this is causing the problem because I removed it & saw the same behavior.

Here's the code:

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()

    Dim csvFileName As String
    Dim ThisWB As Workbook, csvWB As Workbook

    Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook

    ThisWB.Sheets("SourceSheet").UsedRange.Copy

    Set csvWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)

    csvWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Set csvFileName = ThisWB.Path & "\" & ThisWB.Sheets("Instructions").Range("E10").Value & ".csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    csvWB.SaveAs FileName:=csvFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    csvWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "File has been Created and Saved"

End Sub
```

A few more notes:

- The module works fine until I run the `SaveAsCSV` sub.
- The module is saved at the workbook level. It is basically an advanced vlookup w/ concatenation. Moving it within one of the sheets breaks it.
- The `SaveAsCSV` sub is also at the workbook level. Moving it to the "Instructions" sheet doesn't stop the behavior.
- Using Excel for Mac, Version 16.21.1

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Edit:5-23-19

For reference, here is the module code:

```
Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)

Dim i As Long
Dim Result As String

For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
  If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
    For J = 1 To i - 1
    If LookupRange.Cells(J, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
      If LookupRange.Cells(J, ColumnNumber) = LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) Then
        GoTo Skip
      End If
    End If
    Next J
    Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
Skip:
  End If
Next i

MultipleLookupNoRept = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (without the copy/paste):

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()

    Dim csvFileName As String
    Dim ThisWB As Workbook, csvWB As Workbook, rngUsed As Range

    Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook

    Set rngUsed = ThisWB.Sheets("SourceSheet").UsedRange

    csvFileName = ThisWB.Path & "\" & _
           ThisWB.Sheets("Instructions").Range("E10").Value & ".csv" 'no Set!

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(rngUsed.Rows.Count, _
                           rngUsed.Columns.Count).Value = rngUsed.Value

        .SaveAs Filename:=csvFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
                          CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True

        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "File has been Created and Saved"

End Sub
```

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean when you say the module is “launching”

Comment: Thanks for the response. For some reason, the modul still launches after the line:
 
`.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(rngUsed.Rows.Count, _
         rngUsed.Columns.Count).Value = rngUsed.Value\``

I can't tell if the Module is trying to run in the new wb, or if it's recalculating in the old wb. I'm thinking the new, because it yields a 'Run-time error \'1004\': Application-defined or object-defined error`, which would make sense if the module's arguments refer to a sheet back in the source workbook. 


Interestingly, your code doesn't break the modules in the old wb like my code.

Comment: By launching, I mean stepping into that line brings up the module window, and immediately steps into it. Then that module loops until the error 1004

Comment: My code only copies values from one sheet to another - your function will never run in the new worksheet, so that shouldn't be a problem.  However it does seem like *something* is tripping it up.  Can you show an example of how it's called from the worksheet?

Comment: The `SaveAsCSV` sub is called from a button click in the _Instructions_ Sheet. If I call it from the button instead of stepping through the function, the sub still breaks before saving the new wb & after the values have been copied, but I get an Error 400 instead of an Error 1004.  
The `MultipleLookupNoRept` Module runs in two columns on the ExportSheet.

Comment: The problem is with `MultipleLookupNoRept` but I don't see any obvious issues in the code for that function, other than I'm not sure what the purpose of the inner "J" loop is.

Comment: Hmm. I think you're right, but it's odd that the module works on its own until the `SaveAsCSV` sub is called. The internal J loop just prevents duplicates. I'm sure there's a more efficient way to write that part of the code.